# React native error- Expo init not creating project

Tags: reactjs, react-native

After installation of Node JS and NPM. The expo init createprojects brings the following error;

```
throw err;
    ^

Error: Cannot find module 'core-js/library/fn/promise'
    at Function.Module._resolveFilename (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:649:15)
    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:575:25)
    at Module.require (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:705:19)
    at require (internal/modules/cjs/helpers.js:14:16)
    at Object.<anonymous> (C:\Users\KEVIN PC\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\expo-cli\node_modules\babel-runtime\core-js\promise.js:1:31)
    at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:799:30)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:810:10)
    at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:666:32)
    at tryModuleLoad (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:606:12)
    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:598:3)
```

Comment: `npm install` ?

Comment: expo init createproject is supposed to create a project

Comment: it doesnt create the folder with the projects where i'll do npm install

Comment: `After installation of Node JS and NPM.` Did you install expo? `npm install -g expo-cli`

Comment: Executed npm install -g expo-cli